# Get GraphicBuffer from OMX and keep it (block data override from decoder)

Tags: android, c++, multimedia, graphic, stagefright

Could someone help me to keep the graphicbuffer from OMX alive without copy please?

I retrieve a graphicbuffer from Android OMX  using stagefright (in a mediabuffer) and I would like to store it and display it later, while I am still decoding new data.

To do that I can do a memcpy of a graphicbuffer (gborg) as follows:

```
gborg->lock(GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN, (void**)(&imgorg));
gb->lock(GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_WRITE_OFTEN, (void**)(&img));
memcpy(img,imgorg,sizeToCopy);
gb->unlock();
gborg->unlock();
```

The problem is that the copy is too long!

So I tried to create a new graphicbuffer as follows:
    MediaBuffer* buffBis = nex MediaBuffer(gborg);

==> this is quite fast because here I just store the pointer. Normally the graphic buffer will be available as long as I keep a reference on it (principle of smart pointer). Unfortunately, this solution does not work because I keep decoding data and it seems that the decoder writes in gborg new data. Do you know how I could keep the old data without copy as long as I want please? Can we indicate to OMX that a graphicbuffer must not be overriden with new data?